# Can a virtual function access the friend of base class?

Tags: c++

I am just a beginner in C++, my question is can a virtual function access the friend of base class? or the virtual function will only access the class's friend function in which it is defined?

```
class A
{
friend class B;
public:
virtual void setData();
};
```

now if a class is derived from class A

```
class C:public class A{
public:
setData()
{
  //can I use the friend class B here?
}
};
```

Comment: Friendship is not inherited. Do you go out drinking with your mom's friends?

Comment: No, `friend` means that `B` is allowed to use `private` stuff from `A`, not the other way round. And also `friend` relations aren't inherited.

Comment: thanks...I got it.

Comment: Although if it's something A has access to, you can add a protected getter to A, and C can call that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have friendship backwards.  `B` is a friend of `A`, but that gives `A` **zero extra rights** over `B`.

In C++, friendship does not commute.  `A` says `B` is a friend, but `A` may not be a friend of `B`.

Second, friendship is not inherited.  You don't go out drinking with your mother's friends.

Third, there are many ways to republish or share rights.  The class that is a friend can have a method that does the operation on the friend.

Suppose you really wanted this:

```
class B {
  friend class A;
  void doStuff();
};

class A {
public:
  virtual void setData(B* b) = 0;
};

class C:public A{
public:
  virtual void setData(B* b) {
    b->do_stuff();
  }
};
```

`C::setData` generates an error.  But we can change it like this:

```
class A {
protected:
  void do_stuff_on_b(B* b) { b->do_stuff(); }
public:
  virtual void setData(B* b) = 0;
};

class C:public A{
public:
  virtual void setData(B* b) {
    do_stuff_on_b(b);
  }
};
```

we could also generalize this and create an access token:

```
class B {
  struct access_token{ explicit access_token(int) {} };
  friend class A;
public:
  void doStuff(access_token);
};

class A {
protected:
  static B::access_token access_b() { return access_token(0); };
public:
  virtual void setData(B* b) = 0;
};

class C:public A{
public:
  virtual void setData(B* b) {
    b->do_stuff( access_b() );
  }
};
```

where we gatekeep access to `B` private methods based on possession of an access token that can be passed around.  The methods are public, but the token itself can only be created by friends.

Comment: Thanks I got it, but what if the class B is a friend of class C, then can  I easily use it in the virtual function?

Comment: @FarazQureshi No, that is wrong.  I suspect you got friendship backwards, again.